# Continue or quit

Tags: python

I am teaching myself Python. For practice I made a little mad lib game for my daughter. The problem, I want to add a "to continue press enter or type quit to exit" after line 3. I know I'm obviously doing it wrong, but I've tried conditional, flags and breaks with no luck.

```
        #Prompt
        greeting = input("Hello what is your name?       ")
        greeting += input(f" OK {greeting} lets wright a story together. Lets get started" )
               
        #listing of directions
        while True:
               q_1 =input("please type a plural noun :  ")
               q_2 = input("please type an adjective:    ")
               q_3 =input ("please type plural noun, animal:    ")  
               q_4 =input("Please enter an plural noun:  ")
               q_5 = input("Please enter an adjective:   ")
               q_6 = input("Please enter a color: ")
               q_7 = input("Please enter an adjective:   ")
               q_8 = input("Please enter noun:    ")
               q_9 = input("Please enter plural noun:    ")
        
               q_10 =input("Please enter an adjective    ")
               q_11 = input("Please enter a verb: ")
               q_12 = input("Please enter plural noun    ")
               q_13 = input("Please enter a verb-ed:     ")
               q_14 = input("Please enter a verb:    ")
               q_15 = input("Please enter noun:   ")
               q_16 = input("Please enter a adjective:   ")    
               break
               print("Ok here's your story")
    
        # output with data from input
        story = f"""
        Unicorns aren't like other {q_1}; they're {q_2}. They look like
        {q_3}, with {q_4} for feet and a {q_5} mane of hair. But Unicorns
        are {q_6} and have a {q_7} {q_8} on their heads. Some {q_9} don't
        believe Unicorns are {q_10} but I believe in them. I would love to
        {q_11} a Unicorn faraway {q_12}. One thing I've always {q_13} about
        is whether Unicorns {q_14} rainbows, or is their {q_15} {q_16} 
        like any other animals?
        """
        print(story)
```

Comment: FWIW there's a bit of grammar that needs to be fixed in the code - for example the wright usage above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your question, I've suggest something simple like this.

```
#Prompt
greeting = input("Hello what is your name?\n")
print(f"OK {greeting} lets wright a story together. Lets get started")
play = input('to continue press enter or type quit to exit\n')

if play == 'quit':
    quit()

# Rest of your code stays the same
```

I'll mention also, because you said you are doing this for practice, that the way you are asking for inputs is a little bit rough.
In my example above I added a `\n` character. This will stop you needing to use all those spaces by putting the input response on a new line.

Comment: That works. Thank you for your time.

Comment: @getgutts If this solution is acceptable could I ask that you mark it as the accepted answer? Thanks